# cs50 substitution int x = plaintext[i] - 'a';

Tags: c, ascii, cs50

I was trying to do substitution from cs50 pset2 on two loops but I had some issues.

I found one loop solution here: [free(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped) cs50](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61767483/free-invalid-pointer-aborted-core-dumped-cs50)

But now I don't really understand this part:

```
int x = plaintext[i] - 'a';
```

If `plaintext[i]` is `'m'`, `'m'` is 109 in ASCII, and `'a'` is 97, so `m-a == 12`, form feed in ascii. Or it's not an ASCII substraction going on?

Comment: It is integer subtraction, computing the index / offset of ‘m’ relative to ‘a’.

Comment: `x` is just a number between 0 and 25 that represents a letter from `a` to `z`. Later in the code, you'll add `'a'` to get an ASCII letter from `'a'` to `'z'`.

Comment: It gives you the lowercase character in the range `0` .. `25` to use as, say, an array index. Similarly `'9' - '0'` gives `9` the numeric value of the digit character `'9'`. So you need hardly ever be concerned with (or use) the actual ASCII value.

Comment: So if (islower(plaintext[i]))  i = 1 second char of array  representig by letter m. im doing this to pull character from this arrey?
Isn't (islower(plaintext[i])) is m allredy and i could do the same thing without - 'a'? that part I dont understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the next line:

```
printf("%c", tolower(key[x]));
```

x is used as an index into the key array.